# Why doesn't move vector trigger moving internal elements?

Tags: c++

For the following code, I am confused about p3 vector, why move operators are not triggered for Test? For p1 and p2, I can understand that all the elements need to copied be over.

Does that mean when we move a vector, it modifies the vector object so the elements of the vector will leave untouched. Whereas when we copy a vector, we have to copy every single element. Is there a vector operation where the move operator of an element will be trigger?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

class Test {
  public: 
    Test(int a) {
        std::cout << " default " << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test(const Test& o) {
        std::cout << " copy ctor " << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test& operator=(const Test& o) {
        std::cout << " copy assign " << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    
    Test(Test&& o) {
        std::cout << " move ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test& operator=(Test&& o) {
        std::cout << " move assign " << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << " p: " << std::endl;
  std::vector<Test> p = {Test(0), Test(0)}; 
  std::cout << std::endl;
   
  std::cout << " vec p1 " << std::endl;
  std::vector<Test> p1 = p;
  std::cout << std::endl;
    
  std::cout << " vec p2 " << std::endl;
  std::vector<Test> p2;
  p2.reserve(2);
  p2.emplace_back(0);
  p2.emplace_back(0);
  std::cout << std::endl;
   
  std::cout << " vec p3 " << std::endl;
  std::vector<Test> p3 = std::move(p);
}
```

Output:

```
p: 
default 
default 
copy ctor 
copy ctor 

vec p1 
copy ctor 
copy ctor 

vec p2 
default 
default 

vec p3
```

Comment: Please do not add new questions to your question after its been answered. Generally, one question per question is all that's allowed. If you have a follow up question, make a new question, and you can reference this question.

Comment: A move of an element happens when you (move) assign to an element: `p3[0] = Test()`. or for a triple move: std::swap(p3[0], p3[1]);`

Answer (score 8):

A vector is essentially a pointer to an array. Moving the vector simply swaps the array pointers between the two vectors, the arrays themselves are unchanged.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It could still be implemented with swap; the move ctor just delegates to the default constructor, then follows up with a swap (which, because the default constructor initializes to an empty `vector`, would achieve the correct result). You can't tell the difference between swapping from the newly created empty `vector` and explicitly resetting the source to be empty after all.

Comment: The use of swap is not guaranteed. Move assignment leaves the source vector in an unspecfied state.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Here, I've fixed the wording.

Answer (score 4):

`vector` is basically

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
    T* data;
    T* end_data;
    T* end_capacity;
public:
    //...
};
```

When you want to copy that, you need to allocate new space for `data` to point to and then copy the elements from the source vector into the destination.

When moving this doesn't need to happen.  Moving basically empties the source location, which in this case means copying the pointers into the moved to vector and then setting the pointers in the moved from vector to null.  This is why moving can be such a performance gain.

Comment: Thank you! A followup question, is there a vector operation where the move operator of an element will be trigger?

Comment: I feel like this might be slightly improved by compare/contrast with the counter-example where the elements *are* all moved (e.g. making `p3` with `std::vector<Test> p3(std::make_move_iterator(p.begin()),                           std::make_move_iterator(p.end()));` where the new `vector` allocates its own storage, but populates it with moves from the source `vector`).

Comment: @Zack Force resize of the `vector` and if the the move operations are marked `noexcept`, the vector will move them. If the compiler can't prove that an inconsistent state won't result from the move, the `vector` will copy.

Comment: @Zack: Heh, didn't see your comment (it hadn't posted when I began composing that last comment) but the suggested improvement from my last comment would be such an example. The source `vector` `p` remains valid, and has the same size before and after, but all the *elements* in it have indeterminate but legal values (you can't use them until you've reassigned them). It's much more expensive to move all the elements rather than moving the `vector` itself; I can't come up with a reason to do it, but it's possible. As user4581301 notes, `move` is used implicitly in resizing if it's `noexcept`.